# SCSS data-theme="dark" variables doesnt load

Tags: javascript, css, sass, data-theme

im currently working on a dark mode for my site and the JS is working fine, it adds the `data-theme="dark"` parameter to the html tag and stores it in the local storage.
But the variables in SCSS just wont load. Here is my code:

```
$colorMain: #9C27B0;
$colorDisabled: rgb(92, 92, 92);

$colorTextWhite: #FFF;
$colorTextBlack: #000;
$colorTextTitle: #2b2b2b;
$colorTextPara: #4e4e4e;

$colorBgMain: #FFF;
$colorBgSec: darken($colorBgMain, 3%);

$colorAlertSuccess: #8BC34A;
$colorAlertDanger: #F44336;

$colorDarkMode: #272727;

[data-theme="dark"] {
    $colorMain: rgb(176, 39, 39);
    $colorDisabled: rgb(92, 92, 92);

    $colorTextWhite: #FFF;
    $colorTextBlack: #000;
    $colorTextTitle: #2b2b2b;
    $colorTextPara: #4e4e4e;

    $colorBgMain: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    $colorBgSec: darken($colorBgMain, 3%);

    $colorAlertSuccess: #8BC34A;
    $colorAlertDanger: #F44336;

    $colorDarkMode: #ffffff;
}
```

JS:

```
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('input[name="mode"]');

function switchTheme(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        trans()
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark'); //add this
    } else {
        trans()
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light'); //add this
    }    
}

toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);

const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') ? localStorage.getItem('theme') : null;

if (currentTheme) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);

    if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
        toggleSwitch.checked = true;
    }
}

let trans = () => {
    document.documentElement.classList.add('transition');
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        document.documentElement.classList.remove('transition');
    }, 1000)
}
```

Can somebody help me? :D

Comment: Can you add source code to question as text?

Comment: added the code :D

Answer (score 0):

The variables can't just load, you have to use some preprocessing lib to convert them. Alternatively I'd recommend you to use css variables if it fits your use case.

Look second implementation of this [article](https://medium.com/@shra1dhar/adding-dark-theme-to-your-website-under-10-seconds-c54a2c149156?source=friends_link&sk=0cc4d638db1638e8b17ad044d441ebd5). I've tested the code, it should work for you. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

First, define your variables based on the data themes:

```
:root[data-theme="light"] {
  --general-bg-color: #fff
}
:root[data-theme="dark"] {
  --general-bg-color: #333
}
```

Then, use the colors independently of the data theme:

```
.someClass {
   background-color: var(--general-bg-color)
}
```